# Java 8 streams: count values

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get the number of ocurrences of an object in the set of values in a list using Java 8 streams, but I can't get the hang of it yet.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
int threshold = 5;
for (Player player : match) { // match is a Set<Player>
    int count = 0;
    for (Set<Player> existingMatch : matches)
        if (existingMatch.contains(player))
            count++;
    if (count >= threshold )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
}
```

I know I can group with `collect` and `groupingBy`, and use a filter saying that the operation to apply is `contains` with the new method reference operator. But I am still too green with these new Java 8 features and cannot put it all together.

So how could I extract the number of ocurrences of `player` in **all** set of values in a list, using Stream?

Comment: I don't see any Map in the posted code. Why would you use a Map in a stream-based equivalent?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here. Can you share an example of such a map and the output you're trying to get for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lambda expressions can help separate the different bits of logic and then compose them together.

As I understand from your code, you are testing players for whether they are contained in at least `threshold` elements of `matches`.  We can write the test logic as follows:

```
Predicate<Player> illegalTest = player -> matches.stream()
        .filter(m -> m.contains(player))
        .count() >= threshold;
```

Then we want to apply this test to see if any of the players matches:

```
boolean hasIllegal = match.stream().anyMatch(illegalTest);
```

And finally:

```
if (hasIllegal) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
}
```

Comment: Would be more efficient with a `limit(threshold)` after the filter.

Comment: @JBNizet I debated whether to put that in, but decided to keep it simple.